# VueCarousel flex height of child not adjusting on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox, height

I'm using VueCarousel to make a slider on a Vue App.  The problem is that the height of the slider is not setting up on Firefox. Works fine on Chrome and Safari. The images of each slide are as background (happens the same if they are img)

This is the generated html :

```
   <div class="VueCarousel-wrapper">
         <div class="VueCarousel-inner" style="transform: translateX(0px); transition: transform 0.5s ease; flex-basis: 769px; visibility: visible;">
               <div class="VueCarousel-slide" style="background-image:....);">
                </div>
         </div>
   </div>
```

and this is the css

```
   .VueCarousel-wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
   }

   .VueCarousel-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
   }

   .VueCarousel-slide {
    flex-basis: inherit;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: relative;
    height: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
   }
```

that *height 0* is doing nothing

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4VLt.png)
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRMUq.png)

Could you please help me up here?, if you are seeing something wrong. 
Thank you very much

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?